# Baffling java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I am using org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder to upload images to the server, When I tested in version 7 devices, its works fine but in devices 4.x it throughs error like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at runtime. I am not sure where those classes went missing at runtime for 4.x devices.I am using Android Studio 2.3.3.I hope I have messed up Gradle hence the same works fine in 4.x devices when I use the same in a different application.

Build Gradle

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.xx.xx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 32
    versionName "4.0.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
lintOptions{
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
}  
 repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'
  compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.2.1'
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
  compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
  compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.1'
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
  compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
    exclude module: "httpclient"
 }
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Comment: Can you post gradle-wrapper properties file?